# How can I track file and folder modification times with SVN?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Please notice, that this has nothing to with setting `use-commit-times`. I am using SVN to keep track of school work (Word Documents, PDFs, images, etc.). What is necessary to do this? I have things that say to the effect that SVN's arbitrary properties can be used to store this information. How do I do this?

Additional information: I am not talking about the last commit time.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. `svn` does this automatically (`svn log`, or TortoiseSVN's `Show Log` menu item) when you check in a file of any type; it stores the file's date and time stamp, along with the time the file was committed.

Comment: Can you clarify your question: Is it you want the time the file was last modified (I modified it yesterday at 5:15pm) vs. when it was committed? (I committed the change I made yesterday at 5:15pm today at 10:00 in the morning.)

Answer (score 0):

Subversion itself does not store this metadata. You could hack around it some by creating custom properties to record those timestamps, but you would then need to run a script to update them before performing any commit.

The repository only cares about when an item was changed *in the repository*.

Comment: What version control systems do record this property then?

Comment: Git, Bazaar, Mercurial, what?